# Active link background in Navbar doesn't go until the botton

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to  create a navbar with Bootstrap, but in the active link, the backgorund doesn't go until the botton. Where I can change this? She the link HOME in the image. The active background (black) doesn't cover all the gray background from the navbar

[image: NavBar with Active Link with incomplete background]

This is my code:

```
.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
  border-color: #5CAD00;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #214013;
}
```

Comment: Source code would be helpful..

Comment: Ok, already did. Tell me if you need other code that you need

Comment: Its better if you can show us a jsfiddle or live demo.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the CSS for the navbar links. Use this Code. It may vary according to which version of bootstrap you are using.

```
.navbar-inverse .active>a,
.navbar-inverse .active>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .active>a:focus {
  background-color: #DEDEDE  !important; 
}
```

In case it does not work put !important on the css.